# Nuxt.js Loading data serverside with nuxtServerInit and Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

Currently i am working on storing data for a job opening application.
For the backend i use Laravel and for the frontend i use Nuxt.js
I am new to Nuxt, so i'm kinda stuck on the following issue.

I have a page for creating a new job opening called new-job.vue. I also created a store called jobs.js for handling the states.

On new-job.vue i have a form with data that has to be rendered in a list before the form starts.Like a list of all countries etc.. in order for me to select them in the form.

At this point i'm using asyncData within the export default on new-job.vue:

```
<script>
export default {

    asyncData(context) {
        return context.app.$axios
            .$get('jobs/create')
            .then(data => {
                //context.store.dispatch('jobs/getTypes', data.types)
                context.store.dispatch('jobs/getPlatforms', data.platforms)
                context.store.dispatch('jobs/getCountries', data.countries)data.branches)

                // return {
                //     loadedPost: { ...data, id: context.params.postId }
                // }composer required barr
            })
            .catch(e => context.error(e))
    },
     computed: {
         types () { return this.$store.state.jobs.types },
         platforms () { return this.$store.state.jobs.platforms },
         countries () { return this.$store.state.jobs.countries },

    },
}
```

The asyncData method works and the lists of types, platforms and countries are getting filled with data from the database and the state from the Vuex store gets updated. .Only the data is being rendered on the client side.

I prefer this data to be loaded server side, so i was looking at nuxtServerInit. Only can someone explain to me how i can make this happen.

I placed an async call inside the export default of new-job.vue:

```
     async nuxtServerInit ({ commit, state }, { app }) {
        let res = await axios.get(`jobs/create`)

        console.log(res)
        commit('setPlatforms', res.data.platforms)
        commit('setTypes', res.data.types)
        commit('setCountries', res.data.countries)
    },
```

I created the commits in the mutations of the jobs.store, but the states are not being updated.

What am i doing wrong and/or what am i missing?

Or maybe another question, is nuxtServerInit the way to go? Or is loading these lists of data on the clientside not a big deal?

UPDATE:

I use modules mode for the store, so i created a store called jobs.js. Inside this file i tried to call nuxtServerInit as well, but i didn't get any response.

```
nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    return context.app.$axios
        .$get('jobs/create')
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(e => context.error(e))
},
```

Comment: Please, clarify this statement: `I tried an async call within the export default from new-job.vue`. Where did you put `nuxtServerInit`?

Comment: i put nuxtServerInit in new-job.vue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) API reference in Nuxt.js documentation:

> If the action nuxtServerInit is defined in the store, Nuxt.js will call it with the context (only from the server-side).

In other words, it is a reserved store action available only in `store/index.js` file and if defined will be called on server-side before rendering requested routes.

Only `asyncData` and `fetch` methods are available within pages.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. 

I updated my post, with the nuxtServerInit call i used in my jobs.js store file.

Do you maybe have a simple nuxtServerInit call that i can use, so i can see if there is some response?

Comment: `nuxtServerInit` can be used only in `store/index.js` file, as stated above. It can be a file that exports a single action but it will still work. It is not possible to call `nuxtServerInit` elsewhere, even in other store modules.

Comment: Ok that explains why it doesn't work. I thought you can call nuxtServerInit in every store. Thanks for making that clear :) 

Then i rephrase the question a little bit, and ask you if you would have to generate lists for input fields in a form (list of all countries etc.), is the asyncData method a good way to do that? Or would you use a different solution?

Comment: If lists mentioned above are essential for the application and without them it makes no sense to load the page, then I would suggest to use `nuxtServerInit` to fill the store. Otherwise, I would recommend to use `fetch` method of page component to fill the store, simply because it is possible to cache data in vuex and avoid making additional requests during navigation inside the app. This can be done by checking presence of data in the store, before making requests to API.

Comment: Thanks again for commenting. I'm going to try to see if i can get fetch method working. It's not essential for the lists to be loaded right from the start. Just when the create job page opens up the lists needs to be there.

Comment: Is there a client-side alternative for applications that do not use SSR?

Comment: There are various ways to achieve the result in client-side only app. And right solution will depend on kind of data is being fetched. In general, I'd suggest to show loader component initially inside `App.vue` depending on specific state variable (e.g. `dataLoaded`) and dispatch custom store action that will load necessary data. After all data was loaded, update `dataLoaded` variable and display main app content.